# Get function as parameter in haskell

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

I can't figure this, I have a type called Enumeration

```
> type Enumeration a = Int -> [a]
```

And I need to map over it. I wrote this following function:

```
> imapE :: (a -> b) -> Enumeration a -> Enumeration b
> imapE f (m fa) = \n -> imapF f fa
```

where `imapF` is defined like this:

```
> imapF :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b] 
> imapF _ [] = []
> imapF f (x:xs) = f x : imapF f xs
```

but when I try to load my code I get the following error `BinaryTrees.lhs:91:14: Parse error in pattern: m` regarding my `imapE` function.

I am trying to get the first enumeration `Enumeration a` as the function it is (Int and [a])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot pattern match over a function, but you don't have to do that:

```
> imapE :: (a -> b) -> Enumeration a -> Enumeration b
> imapE f g = (imapF f) . g
```

(Well, `imapF` is just `map` really).

Without using `.`:

```
> imapE :: (a -> b) -> Enumeration a -> Enumeration b
> imapE f g = \n -> imapF f (g n)
```

Comment: @EliBraginskiy No it would be `imapF f (g x)`. The `.` is function composition so `f . g = \x -> f (g x)`.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution could be

```
imapE :: (a -> b) -> Enumeration a -> Enumeration b
imapE = map . map
```

Indeed, the above is equivalent to

```
imapE f = map (map f)
```

where

```
f :: a -> b
map f :: [a] -> [b]
map (map f) :: (Int -> [a]) -> (Int -> [b])
```

since both `[]` and `(->) Int` are functors.

The main "trick" to this kind of exercises is to think more about the types than the actual values.

This might feel a bit obscure if you're a beginner. Once you'll get more familiar with functors, however, this will become quite natural.

(People very accustomed to this style could even hint to this solution with some cryptic note "functors compose", and leaving you to figure out what's really going on. When that happens, don't give up -- eventually it will make sense ;-))